# Why objects are not same added to hashset with same value, even hashCode and equals are overriden

Tags: java, equals, hashcode, hashset

Here is the code which produces hashset size 3 instead 2

```
package dump.test;
import java.util.*;
public class WrappedString {
    private String s;
    public WrappedString(String s) { this.s = s; }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<Object> hs = new HashSet<Object>();
        WrappedString ws1 = new WrappedString("aardvark");
        WrappedString ws2 = new WrappedString("aardvark");
        String s1 = new String("aardvark");
        String s2 = new String("aardvark");
        hs.add(ws1); hs.add(ws2); hs.add(s1); hs.add(s2);
        System.out.println(hs.size()+hs.toString()); 
    }
    public boolean equals(Object aSong) {
        String s = aSong.toString();
        System.out.println(s);
        return s.equals(this.s);
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        System.out.println(this.s + "-" + this.s.hashCode());
        return this.s.hashCode();
    }
    /*public int compareTo(Object aSong) {
        String s = aSong.toString();
        return this.s.compareTo(s);
    }*/
}
```

It always print below output if equals and hashCode are overridden
[image]

you can see both objects having same code in output but counted as different and produced count as 3

this is if we do not override equals and hashCode
[image]

Please assist me how this works.

Comment: Your equal method will not even return true for `ws1.equals(ws2)`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your case is not symmetric. If the implementation decides to invoke `equals` on the `String` instance with your class as an argument, it will definitely return false and thus your code will not always work.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian! Which efforts can make two WrappedString objects made above in code are same. I want to produce count as 2 in above code.

Comment: adding public String toString() { return this.s; } cleared my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

From the JavaDoc for the Set interface:

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models the mathematical set abstraction.

So, `HashSet` checks the `equals(Object)` before adding the new element. As the second String is equal to the first, it's not added. On your `WrappedString`, you are not overriding the `equals(Object)`, so, you are using the one inherited from `Object`, which simply checks the object IDs (`659e0bfd` and `2a139a55` in your case).

Comment: Thanks jpkrohling! what about if it encounters object ID 2fcf3776 (as per first image)? so I think both IDs are same and equals will find values are too same and it will be added as one in set but it is not. Which efforts can make two WrappedString objects made above in code are same. I want to produce count as 2 in above code.

Comment: In fact, my answer is not 100% correct, as Object compares the internal ID for an object. For your code to work, I'd say that you'll need to make your WrappedString#equals to compare the internal String's and make your toString return the underlying string.

Comment: kudos jpkrohling! it works as you said. I needed to override one more factory method, toString and made it to return underlaying string value. Previously it couldn't cast properly from object to string and could that lead to different objects in spite having same object IDs. below little snippet works:

public String toString() {
  return this.s;
 }

Answer (score 0):

adding

`public String toString() { 
    return this.s; 
}`

cleared my confusion. Previously it couldn't convert true value from casting object to string and needed to override toString to return underlying value.